# How to show a particular record in DetailsView?

Tags: asp.net, objectdatasource, detailsview

I have a `DetailsView` control which is bind to a `ObjectDataSource`. In my application there is a  `TextBox`, user enter ID in this textbox and clicks SHOW RECORD button, now DetailsView should show that record.

I am not able to show that record in DetailView.

Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
_dataSet.Filter = String.Format("id = {0}", _textBox.Text);
_detailsView.DataSource = _dataSet;
_detailsView.DataBind();
```